# Why does 'on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' doesn't update when same data is updated?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, sql-update

When i have a table with the following data:

```
StatementID(int AI) | created_by(int) | changed_when(onUpdate CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7                   | 4               | 2013-02-26 12:05:57  
8                   | 4               | 2013-02-26 12:20:12
```

I have the following Query:

```
mysql_query('
  UPDATE table 
  SET created_by = 4 
  WHERE statementID=8');
```

When I edit the statement info(other tbl) and it is edited by the same user as last time, the changed_when doesn't update.

Why does the field `changed_when` not change when I update `created_by` with the same data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. onUpdate CURRENT_TIMESTAMP fields update when the values of fields change, not when they stay the same.

To achieve what you seem to want, you can do

```
UPDATE table 
SET created_by = 4,
changed_when = null,
WHERE statementID = 8
```

Answer (score 6):

If in any of the update statement if the value remains same then the timestamp value wont be updated.

From Mysql SITE

If the column is auto-updated, it is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. `The column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values`. To prevent the column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value.

Solution

`To update the column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).`

[Refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)